# First time setting up foursquare api with php

Tags: php, oauth, foursquare

I try to get venues by foursquare api. The steps that I tried are:

- registered my app;
- obtain access_token;
- download the foursquare-aync library

this is the code that I try to used but it didn't work:

```
require_once("Api_Foursquare_EpiCurl");
require_once("Api_Foursquare_EpiFoursquare");
require_once("Api_Foursquare_EpiSequence");

$fsObj = new EpiFoursquare($clientId, $clientSecret, $accessToken);
$venue = $fsObj->get('/venues/search', array('ll' => "{$myLat},{$myLng}"));
```

In particular I didn't understand the functionality of the callback that I set up in the registration.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work with this:

```
$consumer_key = 'YOURS';
$consumer_secret = 'YOURS';

//Includes the foursquare-asyc library files                                                                       
require_once('EpiCurl.php');
require_once('EpiSequence.php');
require_once('EpiFoursquare.php');

try{
  $foursquareObj = new EpiFoursquare($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
  $venue = $foursquareObj->get('/venues/search',array('ll'=>'{your-lat},{your-long}'));
  var_dump($venue);
} catch (Execption $e) {
  //If there is a problem throw an exception                                                                       
}
```

dumps out expected loc data from 4Square.

I'm using January 06, 2011 vers of EpiCurl, EpiSequence, and February 25, 2011 ver of EpiFoursquare.

Answer (score 1):

The call back URL is where Foursquare directs the user after they successfully authenticate with the Foursquare service. So if you're doing local development (using WAMP + php for example) set your callback address to http://localhost/YOUR_PAGE_NAME.php

So what's gonna happen is this;

- Someone visits your page
- Your page prompts them with a link
  which points to Foursquare (this link has in it your application's clientId + secret, letting foursquare know that this user wishes to subscribe to your application)
- Foursqaure prompts the user to log in
  and allow the application requesting
  access
- Foursquare redirects and passes a
  token back to the external
  application, this token can then be
  used for all subsequent requests on
  behalf of the user

  I hope this helps somewhat.

Although I notice you're probably using this tutorial - http://www.joesiewert.com/2010/04/how-to-use-the-foursquare-api-with-oauth-and-php/

Which is now out of date. Also I've found in the past couple of days the that Foursquare-async library is throwing errors for me too, and I don't know why. I've posted here for help;
http://groups.google.com/group/foursquare-api/browse_thread/thread/cd258a78d8073f86/ed5ff3f9fed206ed#ed5ff3f9fed206ed

Andy